# Dynamic 2D array of strings where the second dimension can change

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, memory-management

So I have to make a 2-d array of strings named `history[][]`, where `history[i]` stores all of the subjects currently involved in experiment `i`, and `history[i][j]` contains a string listing all of the experiments that this particular subject has been a part of. The thing is, I have to use `int* numsubjects`, an array of integers that tells me how many subjects are in experiment `i`. However, the contents of `numsubjects` should be able to move around as subjects can be moved into other experiments. I have no idea how to go about doing this. I cannot use `vector`, `dequeue`, or `list`.

```
        experiments = 0;
        numsubjects = new int[experiments+1];
        numsubjects[experiments] = n;
        history = new string*[0];
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          history[0] = new string[j];
          history[0][j] = "0";
        }
```

The above code initializes everything when there is only one experiment, experiment 0. I need a way to make history somehow with numsubjects in it.

Comment: What have you tried so far, please show some code

Comment: Unless this is for an assignment where you are forbidden to use standard containers, try [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

Answer (score 0):

If you must use C-style arrays, then [`realloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) will allow you to resize your array.

However, since this is C++, I strongly encourage you to use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).